# Descartes`s Rule in subject GRE exam.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gre-exam

I am solving this question:[image]

And I found the following answer [image]

I do not understand why there is one sign change in $f$, could anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two coefficients have a positive sign and the third one has a negative sign. Therefore there is exactly one sign change.

Answer (score 1):

$2x^5+8x-7$ is an increasing function and odd degree polynomials have at least one root so the answer is $1$.

Comment: after saying **at least 1**, how can you conclude that it has **exactly** one real root ?

Comment: because the function is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

While the book is doing an IMHO terrible job of explaining it, the number of 'sign changes' being referenced is not the sign changes in the *function* itself, but rather the number of sign changes in the sequence of coefficients $\langle a_n, a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_1, a_0\rangle$ (note that zero coefficients need to be removed here).  In the case under offer here, the sequence is is $\langle 2, 8, -7\rangle$; this has one sign change when going from $8$ to $-7$, so the maximum number of positive roots of the function is $1$.  Descartes's rule also says that the actual number of roots varies from this value by an even number; in other words, it can be two less than this, four less, etc.  But in this case, two less is already $-1$ and it's impossible to have a negative number of roots, so the number of positive roots of the function must be exactly $1$.

To find the maximum number of negative roots, we apply the same rule to the function $f(-x)$; as the book notes, this function has sequence $\langle -2, -8, -7\rangle$ and there are no sign changes in this sequence (all the terms are negative) so there can be no negative zeroes.  (This technique tells you nothing about whether $0$ itself is a zero of the polynomial, but that's true if and only if the constant coefficient of the polynomial is zero, which it isn't here).

For more information, I recommend reading either the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) or [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html) pages on Descartes' sign rule.